# How to check the count of calls per post in Serverless Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

I created a Lambda function using Serverless.

I made it possible to make multiple Post calls to one function, but I want to figure out where the bottleneck occurs.

```
app.post('/a', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/b', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/c', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/d', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/e', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/f', async(req, res) => {};
app.post('/g', async(req, res) => {};
```

Is there a way for me to figure out where in my AWS Lambda function the bottleneck is occurring?

I would like to first figure out which part is being called the most. However, I checked AWS Lambda and API Gateway and couldn't see the number of calls per item.

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use logger to log each step or response. Perhaps then you will be able to check cloudwatch logs to determine where the problem occured. Native logger for your language should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In each call you may want to log the execution and duration details by just using console.log(). After that, run the lambda under "Test" tab and see the Log output below and just "Click here" to view the logs details.

You may also go to "Monitor" tab and click "View CloudWatch logs" in case you are running the lambda outside the console.

Remember that the more details you put in the logs, the more it will become meaningful.

```
app.post('/a', async(req, res) => {
    console.log("This will be logged in CloudWatch")
    console.log(startTime)

    // insert your code here

    console.log(endTime)
    console.log(result)
};
```